# How to show Dialog while clicking a specific tab in tabView of PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, tabview, jsf-2.2

I'm new to jsf and I'm using Primefaces 4.0 to write a tabView. 
I want to do something in my Backing Bean when specific tab is clicked, so I tried this:

page:

```
<p:tabView effect="fade" effectDuration="normal">
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{myConsoleBean.onTabChange}" update=":rightForm"/>

            <p:tab title="My">
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab id="statTab" title="Stat">
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
```

Backing Bean:

```
public void onTabChange(final TabChangeEvent event) {
            TabView tv = (TabView) event.getComponent();
            int activeTabIndex = tv.getActiveIndex();
            System.out.println(activeTabIndex);
            if(activeTabIndex==1)//Stat tab clicked
            {                    
                //do something here...
            }
   }
```

Everything works till now,but the Backing Bean is slow for some reason,I want to show a Dialog which contains a progress bar  while the Backing Bean is progressing:

Dialog like this:

```
<p:dialog id="pBarDialog" header="Progressing..." widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" height="70" resizable="false" closable="false">  
    <h:outputText value="Please wait, we're generating your info..." />  
    <p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="100" styleClass="animated">     </p:progressBar>  
 </p:dialog>
```

So, how can I show the dialog when I click the "Stat" tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I resolved this problem.
I used `p:remoteCommand` after I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173811/cannot-show-dialog-in-primefaces-requestcontext-execute-call).

And here's my final codes:

Page:

```
            <p:tabView effect="fade" effectDuration="normal">
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{myConsoleBean.onTabChange}" oncomplete="dlg.hide()" update=":rightForm"/>
            <p:tab title="My">

            </p:tab>
            <p:tab id="statTab" title="Stat">
                <p:remoteCommand actionListener="#{myConsoleBean.goToUrl('myStat.xhtml')}" update=":rightForm" name="showStat" global="true" onstart="dlg.show()" oncomplete="dlg.hide()"></p:remoteCommand>
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>

        <p:dialog id="pBarDialog" header="Progressing..." widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" height="70" resizable="false" closable="false">  
            <h:outputText value="Please wait, we are generating your info..." />  
            <p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="100" styleClass="animated">  
            </p:progressBar>  
        </p:dialog>
```

Bean:

```
 public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
            TabView tv = (TabView) event.getComponent();
            int activeTabIndex = tv.getActiveIndex();
            if(activeTabIndex==1)
            {
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("showStat()");
            }
   }
```

No matter how, thank you both,Lamq and Emil Kaminski.
I will never find that thread without your help because I type key words from your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this :

```
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
    TabView tv = (TabView) event.getComponent();
    int activeTabIndex = tv.getActiveIndex();
    System.out.println(activeTabIndex);
    if(activeTabIndex==1)//Stat tab clicked
    {                    
        //do something here...
    }
    if(activeTabIndex==2){
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dlg').show()"); //For Primeface 4.0
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("dlg.show()"); //Before Primeface 4.0
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why it's not working.
But my problem has resolved with Emil Kaminski's solution.
However, thank you very much!

Comment: I believe this is a good solution. I'll use this solution if I can. Don't know if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: What is your version of primefaces ?

Comment: I use primefaces version 4.0

Comment: Ok so use only `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dlg').show()");` what is your activeTabIndex when you select stat tab ? do you have javascript error ?

Comment: It shows nothing while I use "RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dlg').show()"); " or even "RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("dlg.show()");"

Comment: No, there is no javascript error.
when I select stat tab, activeTabIndex is 0, and I put the code in the corresponding section. like this:
`public final void onTabChange(final TabChangeEvent event) {
                TabView tv = (TabView) event.getComponent();
                int activeTabIndex = tv.getActiveIndex();
                System.out.println(activeTabIndex);
                if(activeTabIndex==1)
                {
                    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dlg').show()");
                    
                }
       }`

Comment: I've tried `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF(pBarDialog).show()")` but it still shows nothing. Orz

Comment: delete final from TabChangeEvent and method. Now you should have activeTabIndex different to 0 ?

Comment: Sorry, my fault.
When I select stat tab, activeTabIndex is "1".
(I've delete final from TabChangeEvent)

Comment: with RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('pBarDialog').show()") ? or RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dlg').show()") ?

Comment: I tried both, but they are the same. No error message, no dialog shown.

Comment: `public void onTabChange(final TabChangeEvent event) {

                TabView tv = (TabView) event.getComponent();

                int activeTabIndex = tv.getActiveIndex();

                System.out.println(activeTabIndex);

                if(activeTabIndex==1)
                {
                    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF(pBarDialog).show()");

                    
                }
       }`

Comment: you have forgot ' and ' between pBarDialog and it's dlg so PF('dlg').show()

Comment: Still not work...

`public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
                TabView tv = (TabView) event.getComponent();
                int activeTabIndex = tv.getActiveIndex();
                if(activeTabIndex==1)
                {
                    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dlg').show()");
                    goToUrl("myStat.xhtml");
                }
       }`

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use the visible attribute on the dialog:

```
<p:dialog id="pBarDialog" header="Progressing..." visible="#{myConsoleBean.showDialog}"
    modal="true" height="70" resizable="false" closable="false">
```

In your bean:

```
private boolean showDialog;

public void displayDialog() {
    showDialog = true;
}

public boolean getShowDialog() {
    return showDialog;
}
```

And then

```
 if(activeTabIndex==1)//Stat tab clicked
            {                    
                myConsoleBean.displayDialog();
            }
```

Also be sure that your ajax components updates the dialog

Comment: Sorry, I found the dialog shows even I click other tabs, is there something I should do to fix it?

Comment: Sorry i didn't fully read your question, I missed the part where the dialog should only appear on specific tabs. See my updated answer

Comment: Like this?
`public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
                TabView tv = (TabView) event.getComponent();
                int activeTabIndex = tv.getActiveIndex();
                if(activeTabIndex==1)
                {
                    displayDialog();
                    goToUrl("myStat.xhtml");
                }
       }
private boolean showDialog;

public void displayDialog() {
    showDialog = true;
}

public boolean getShowDialog() {
    
    return showDialog;
}`

Comment: However,it shows nothing before "goToUrl("myStat.xhtml"); "done. Because when I click Stat tab, it just refresh "showDialog", and the method returns after my "goToUrl("myStat.xhtml"); " function done. So the dialog will show after things are done, while I want the dialog shows when "goToUrl("myStat.xhtml"); " running.