# p:ajaxStatus doesn't work for the second request

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Prior to showing the edit dialog, a loading gif is used to display the progress.

```
<p:dataTable id="accounts">
    <p:column>
        <p:commandButton
            action="#{accountsBean.initializeAccount}" process="@this"
            oncomplete="accountsDialogWidget.show()" update=":accountsDialog">                                   
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog id="accountsDialog"
    widgetVar="acccountsDialogWidget" dynamic="true" modal="true">        
    <h:form id="objectWizardForm">
        ...
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

The `ajaxStatus` component is this:

```
<p:ajaxStatus id="loading">
    <f:facet name="start">
        <h:graphicImage name="loading.gif" library="images" styleClass="loadingStatus" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="complete">
        <h:outputText value="" />
    </f:facet>
</p:ajaxStatus>
```

There are two Ajax requests being made, but the ajaxStatus displays the gif image only for the first one.

First request:

```
form    form
form:agents_input   WindowsAD
form:accounts:3:j_...   form:accounts:3:j_idt71
form:accounts_sele...   
form:type_input WINDOWS
javax.faces.ViewState   e2s1
javax.faces.partial.ajax    true
javax.faces.partial.execute form:accounts:3:j_idt71
javax.faces.partial.render  accountsDialog
javax.faces.source  form:accounts:3:j_idt71
```

Second request:

```
accountsDialog  accountsDialog
accountsDialog_contentLoa...    true
form    form
form:agents_input   WindowsAD
form:accounts_sele...   
form:type_input WINDOWS
javax.faces.ViewState   e2s1
javax.faces.partial.ajax    true
javax.faces.partial.execute accountsDialog
javax.faces.partial.render  accountsDialog
javax.faces.source  accountsDialog
```

Why doesn't ajaxStatus work for the second request? I am using PrimeFaces 3.4.2 and JSF Mojarra 2.1.13.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show ajaxstatus for dynamic Primefaces components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099688/how-to-show-ajaxstatus-for-dynamic-primefaces-components)

Comment: It's not exactly the same question, but your comment helped me find the cause. Please formulate a short answer to mark it as the solution. Maybe this question will help others. If you consider that this question should not exist, I will delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After updating components after an ajax action, the p:ajaxstatus didn't work any more.

This worked for me:

Just add the p:ajaxstatus-id into the update list:

```
<p:ajaxStatus id="aj">...</p:ajaxStatus>

<h:form>
    <p:commandButton ... update=":aj">...</p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

now it works again, seems like the ajaxStatus need to know about the "updated" components to register them again (for monitoring for second, third... ajax requests).

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently facing similar issue for one of my <p:ajax> request. I found that the ajax call itself was not invoked through PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest. I have also found out the root cause for the same. when we don't set "async='true'" in <p:ajax>, it redirects the request to RequestManager to invoke the ajax call instead. I see one problem there, the offer method invokes the ajax call only when the requests array length is 1, in an assumption that requests variable will always be instantiated and thus, the length will be 1, but the requests variable is still holding the previous object when invoked for second time. This is because either the browser stores the requests variable and keeps pushing the new entry in to it or jQuery is handling it. So, for the second requests onwards, it is not invoking the ajax call. After setting "async='true'", the issue got resolved. To mention the versions, my PrimeFaces is 1.1 and jQuery currently upgrading to 1.12.4, and that's where the issue arises. The same code piece was working fine with jQuery 1.4.2.

```
if (b.async) {
    jQuery.ajax(d);
} else {
    PrimeFaces.ajax.RequestManager.offer(d);
}

PrimeFaces.ajax.RequestManager = {
    requests: new Array(),
    offer: function(a) {
        this.requests.push(a);
        if (this.requests.length == 1) {
            var b = jQuery.ajax(a);
            if (b === false) {
                this.poll()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PrimeFaces 1.1???? Why not fully upgrade instead of just jquery? That is asking for more troubles and workarounds for which JSF or PrimeFaces are not to blame...

Comment: Exactly, I agree to that fact. In my current timeline, I wouldn't be able to upgrade PrimeFaces, so proceeded with only jQuery that too only upto 1.12.4. Worst part is, JSF is also outdated with 1.1, so to upgrade PrimeFaces, even for 2.0, it requires JSF 2.0 as well. So, I might end up in touching Java components as well. That's the reason why I wanted to stick with just jQuery for time being and yes, I've been trying to patch up here and there due to this partial upgrade activity.